# problem adding success to jquery post

Tags: jquery

I have this code here and want to attach a success function but dont know how. Can anyone please advise?

```
$.post('SendEmail.aspx',
         {emailbody: emailBody})
```

Answer (score 2):

See the examples, it's pretty straightforward.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('SendEmail.aspx', {emailbody: emailBody}, function(result) {
    //success function here
})
```

EDIT

If you want to handle errors, you need to call the full $.ajax() function like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'SendEmail.aspx',
    data: {emailbody: emailBody},
    success: function(result){ //success function code},
    error: function(result){ //error function code},
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Check out this link for all the [ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: @jack -- if you want to handle failure, you need to use the full $.ajax() function, rather than the $.post shorthand function. See edit.

Comment: both success/error are alerting me with the same result even though the failure didnt go through.

Comment: @jack - you've got a bug in your code then; error and success are mutually exclusive.